# Russian equivalents of "have ideas above his station"

Tags: выражения, английский

In conversation, one of my colleagues said:

> He's thinking of making advances to the hospital director's daughter. If you ask me, he'**s got ideas above his station**. He's not set up for life or anything!

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in Russian. This expression means something like:

- *He's hoping for (/ He thinks he is qualified for) something unsuitable for someone of his social position*.

I guess this is one of those expressions that do not translate easily into other languages. How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian?

Answer (score 6):

**Слишком высоко замахнулся**

slang - **слишком губу раскатал**

Comment: Also _он хочет *прыгнуть выше [своей] головы*_.

Answer (score 5):

I like more "*Не по Сеньке шапка*" (i.e. "Not a cap for Simon boy"; until 18th century Russian nobles wore a high cap).

But there are some more: *со свиным рылом в калашный ряд*, *не по себе сук рубит* etc.

Comment: Не его поля ягода

Answer (score 3):

> If you ask me, he's got ideas above his station.

По-моему, он чересчур много о себе возомнил.

Something like that.

In colloquial language you might hear phrases like:

"берега потерял", "рамсы попутал"(not recommended).

Related proverbs:

*Всяк сверчок - знай свой шесток.*

*По одежке протягивай ножки.*

Answer (score 2):

Pertinent is this juicy saying:

"широко шагаешь -- штаны порвёшь"

This means: excessive are your ambitions, and this may not end well

Answer (score 1):

The examples you've been given are pretty bad to use in everyday speech. the "Слишком высоко замахнулся, slang - слишком губу раскатал" is belittling to the person you say this to/about and shows your dislike of that person. The others are used only in literature.

How i've heard it said, and would most likely say, is "она-девушка не его калибра" (she is a woman of not his calibre). it's as neutral as you can say that, in my head.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning attitude you wish to paint it, which attitudes you have to the person who try to do so.

I like that comment from Elena

> Не его поля ягода

And in the situation, it needs some modifications, but it would be light and relatively positive expression towards the boi

> Паренек решил подкатить к дочке директора, но ягодка не [с] его поля.

in a sense, yeah sure it maybe smart move on his side based his situation, but chances are slim and he is aiming well above his head

Answer (score 0):

One more option is "Он слишком высоко метит" as I think this situation is related to different social groups issue. "Она не чета ему" which means that she has a higher social status.